# JS / jQuery — почему не получается выполнить программный клик по кнопке?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Делаю бота для одного сайта на JS. Подгружаю свой JS файл через закладку в браузере, есть такой способ.

Использую браузер Google Chrome, пробую с помощью jQuery выполнить клик по кнопке на этом сайте, но почему то не получается.

Не рекламы ради конечно, собственно сам сайт вот: 
[alpari[dot]ru/ru/binary_options/](http://alpari[dot]ru/ru/binary_options/)

Кликать необходимо по кнопке `"ВЫШЕ"`. Пробовал двумя способами:

```
$("div.bali-grid__call_put button.bali-button_type_green").trigger("click");
```

---

```
var event = $.Event('click'); 
event.clientX = 1010; 
event.clientY = 805; 
$('div.bali-grid__call_put button.bali-button_type_green').trigger(event);
```

Но клик не происходит. Возможно как то сделан запрет на программный клик, но пока не понял как.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй простой клик:

```
  $("div.bali-grid__call_put button.bali-button_type_green")[0].click();
```

trigger("click") - не подходит для клика по ссылке, он запускает событие. Еще можно посмотреть в сторону возможностей location

```
 var your_url = $("a").attr("href");
 location = your_url;
```

Comment: Кажется здесь не нужен индекс, иначе будет нативный элемент

Comment: клик без индекса вернет в консоль объект элемента, а с индексом сработает перенаправление. Вот как-то так: http://pixs.ru/showimage/testjpg_8978109_24435982.jpg

Comment: Какое перенаправление? Он возвращает jquery объект, и тоже вызывает событие.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f0k3gchv/ - вот так наглядно

Comment: К jQuery это никакого отношения не имеет. Вот исправленный пример - https://jsfiddle.net/f0k3gchv/1/. Чтобы эмулировать клик по ссылке, вызывается событие клик на дочернем элементе. Либо используется нативный метод click(), который сам все сделает.